# What joins will accomplish my goal? (Filtering in sql)

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to filter down the results of a query and I can't quite get the behaviour I'm looking for.

I have a table item which has a primary key id.

There are several properties which *may* exist, and it's the "may" that's causing me the problem.  If the property is met or if the property does not exist I want the item to be included in the results.

For the properties which must exist I use an `INNER JOIN` to get exactly what I want.

For those that *may* exist I'm getting the results where the property is met, but not where it's empty.

For example

```
SELECT id, name
FROM item
INNER JOIN itemWhereTable ON 
( item.id = itemWhereTable.itemID AND itemWhereTable.locationID = 13 )
INNER JOIN itemColorTable ON 
( item.ID = itemColorTable.itemID AND itemColorTable.ColorID = 2 )
WHERE 
item.minCost <=50
```

I'd also like to see the results where the ColorId is not set (ie some packaging is generic and only the specific ones are tracked) ie where the 2nd `INNER JOIN` returns an empty result.

I've tried a `LEFT JOIN` but it doesn't seem to be quite what I need.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can u do `AND itemColorTable.ColorID IS NULL`?

Comment: @dave Would that be produced because the join produced an interim row that had the item id but nothing to match it with?

Comment: As long as it has an ItemID AND ColorID is not set, it will show the id and name

Comment: @dave I think that's got it but I used `INNER JOIN itemalignTable ON (
item.ID = itemColorTable.itemID
AND (
itemColorTable.ColorID =2
OR itemColorTable.ColorID IS NULL
)
)` which seems to work, simple and to the point, thanks much!  Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
AND itemColorTable.ColorID IS NULL
```

Or `AND itemColorTable.ColorID = 2 OR itemColorTable.ColorID IS NULL`